# JS | deep clone object partially

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is there a way to do a shallow copy all fields of `obj1`, but to do to deep clone of inner object `deep_clone` ?

`let obj1 = {first: 'a', shallow_data: {a: 'a', b: 'b'}, deep_clone: {deep1: 1, deep2: 2} };`

`let obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1));` // full deep clone

so here I would like `obj2` to be exactly the same as `obj`, except for `deep_clone`.

The motivation for this is that I have a big object and I need to improve performance and not to deep clone the entire object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use spread syntax to combine shallow and deep copying.

```
let ob2 = {...obj1, deep_clone: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1.deep_clone)) };
```

`...obj1` will shallow-copy the object, then the explicit assignment to the `deep_clone:` property will replace that property with deep copy.

If the `deep_clone` property is just one level deep, you can just use spread syntax there as well:

```
let ob2 = {...obj1, deep_clone: {...obj1.deep_clone} };
```